# Mapping Neo4J result to java object

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Spring provides `@QueryResult` annotation to map the returned values to a java object. But seems like the class annotated with `@QueryResult` can have only instance variables of primitive type. If it is an object then it gets mapped to `Map<String, Object>`.

Is there any way to map this `Map<String, Object>` to a java object? I tried but keep getting null value

For instance,

`MATCH (n{name:'x'}) return {id: ID(n), labels: labels(n)}`

Want to match return value of this query to

```
@QueryResult
class QueryResult{
    NodeInfo node;
}

class NodeInfo{
   Long id;
   String []labels;
}
```

Mapping works if class is defined as

```
@QueryResult
class QueryResult{
   Map<String, Object> node;
}
```

Comment: Which version of SDN?

Comment: @Luanne latest 4.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported- converting a Map to a POJO.

You might be able to eventually define a converter (NodeInfo<->Map) but that won't work in the current version.

Please open a feature request at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH/to support converters if you'd like this item to be discussed by the team.